# Dynamic routing results in 404

Tags: next.js

Following [this guide](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/clean-urls-with-dynamic-routing/dynamic-routing), I created the following file in my project:

*/pages/user/[id].js*

```
class Post extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Navbar />
                <Content />
                <Footer />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Post;
```

But when I go to that URL, I get a 404.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're visiting (for example), `http://localhost:3000/user/something` (where `something` is your `id`), try also visiting `http://localhost:3000/user/something/` (note the backslash). This is currently a known issue in Next with dynamic routing.

(This also assumes you don't have `pages/user/something.js` in your project as dynamic routes take a back seat to explicitly named routes.)